# Cakephp: Correct way to resolve hasMany - hasMany relation

Tags: php, cakephp

I have three models:

Company, Car, Passenger

> Company hasMany Cars
>
> Car hasMany Passenger

These relations seem to work independetly: Car shows all Passengers and Company shows all Cars.

But I cannot resolve the Company - Passenger (Show all Passengers of a Company).

My controller for Company:

```
   function index(){
      //grab all companies and pass it to the view:
      $companies = $this->Company->find('all');
      $this->set('companies', $companies);
   }
```

This displays all companies with all their respective cars. However the array does not contain an entry for passenger.

What do I have to do to completely resovle the Company - Car - Passenger relation?

Comment: Shouldn't you have a join table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (*if doesn't, check your `belongsTo` & `hasMany` relationships*)

```
$this->Company->recursive = 2;
$companies = $this->Company->find('all');
```